# System Error 122 - ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER when calling WriteMsgQueue()

Tags: c++, c, struct, sizeof

'm new to C++ so still trying to get my head around the code so sorry for sounding stupid!

I'm making changes to some existing code.

The old code is calling the below function where the cbDataSize is being determined by sizeof(MyStruct)

```
BOOL WINAPI WriteMsgQueue(HANDLE hMsgQ, LPVOID lpBuffer, DWORD cbDataSize, DWORD dwTimeout, DWORD dwFlags);
```

The change I made was to add another Struct within the Struct MyStruct so that it now looks like:

```
struct MyInnerStruct {
    char myarray[20][256];
    long mycount; 
};

struct MyStruct {
    long value1;
    long value2;
    MyInnerStruct inner;  
};
```

Below is the call to WriteMsgQueue:

```
HANDLE requestQueue;
MyStruct myData;
DWORD timeout = 12000;

WriteMsgQueue(requestQueue, &myData, sizeof(myData), timeout, 0);
```

I am now receiving the `System Error 122` - `ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER` when the `WriteMsgQueue()` is being called.

Any help appreciated on how I calculate the correct size?

Comment: I can't see any call to WriteMsgQueue() in your code. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee488786.aspx says, that 
ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER means "The size of lpBuffer was too small to hold a message."

Comment: Show call to WriteMsg.. and parameters sent to it and allocation done for variables..

Comment: Please use four spaces for code (paste the code and click the {} button). Anyway, spending some time to learn C++ before using the Windows API will go a long way. Your `MyStruct` doesn't have an instance of `MyInnerStruct`, only a forward declaration.

Comment: @chris Sorry That was a typo which I have fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The queue probably wasn't allocated with enough space to hold your larger structure. You may need to find where the old code creates the queue (via `CreateMsgQueue()`) and look at the [`MSGQUEUEOPTIONS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa915345.aspx) struct being passed in. This struct has a `cbMaxMessage` field which determines the maximum size of a single message. You may need to increase this. Also check the other fields like `cbSize`, `dwMaxMessages` etc.

Comment: Perfect thanks. It was the cbMaxMessage value needed to be increased.